# not able to index a document using elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

This is the first time I am trying to use Elastic Search. I am unable to feed data to it.

here is the command (Having issues with this command):

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty -d {"name":"John"}
But if I give the same command as below,its working:

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty -d {"name":true}
Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Can you try to enclose your JSON within single quotes? `...-d '{"name":"John"}'`

Comment: What is your mapping for that field?